# C++: Unexpected result of comparison operators > and string literals

Tags: c++, pointers

In C++ the std::string class implements the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp). 
Following code prints `AAA`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    if("9">"111")
        cout << "AAA";
    else 
        cout << "not AAA";

    return 0;
}
```

and this snippet prints `not AAA` :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    if("9">"111")
        cout << "AAA";
    else 
        cout << "not AAA";

    if("99">"990")
        cout << "BBB";

    return 0;
}
```

Why it is so?

Comment: Where in your code are you using a `std::string`?  `"blah"` is not a `std::string`.

Comment: Distinguish `std::string` and C-string.

Comment: You are comparing `const char*` values, not `std::string`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted. This is a perfectly natural mistake to make, and the question itself is clearly asked and includes a reproducible example. This seems vindictive even for SO.

Comment: @NirFriedman Not saying it is the reason used and I didn't vote but lack of research is a valid reason and figuring out what `"blah"` is, is something the OP should have been able to look up

Comment: To use `std::string`, somewhere you need to declare, cast, or specify `std::string` in some way in your program.  C++ doesn't magically turn  string literals into `std::string` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing addresses of string literals which are somewhere on *static duration storage* and it has unspecified behavior.

Use `std::string` like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    if(std::string("9") > std::string("111"))
        cout << "AAA";
    else 
        cout << "not AAA";

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

With `using namespace std::literals;` one can use "9"s and "111"s.

Thank you @sp2danny

Comment: There is no _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Note that it suffices to only make one of them a `std::string`.

Comment: @user0042 - Comparing two pointers that *do not* point to elements of the same array has undefined behavior.

Comment: @StoryTeller Actually, it seems to be merely unspecified.

Comment: @NirFriedman - Either way, a shaky foundation to write portable source code upon.

Comment: @StoryTeller No disagreement but answers should be correct, and undefined and unspecified are rather different. Filip, would you consider making the correction?

Comment: @NirFriedman - This is splitting hairs somewhat. The only difference is that the range of exhibited behaviors is limited. Compilers still don't have to explain what they are up to.

Comment: with `using namespace std::literals;` one can use `"9"s` and `"111"s`

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's not splitting hairs. That "only" difference is huge. It's the difference between the program being completely invalid, and simply not knowing whether it will print `"AAA"` or `"not AAA"`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - You know, despite the nasal-demon related fear mongering, undefined behavior doesn't mean all it's chalked up to be. So the contract is really narrow in one case, and less narrow in another. No computers are going to burn either way, and you still can't predict what the program will do. Splitting hairs it is. The difference is only of interest if you are a compiler writer.

Comment: @StoryTeller an unspecified value is still a value; in OP's example the program _will_ print either "AAA" or "not AAA". If the behaviour was undefined, it would not necessarily do so. The difference is somewhat more significant than you make out, IMO.

Comment: @davmac - It's not significant if you care about the behavior of your program. Well written code should not exhibit either form of behavior. The difference is in the set of outcomes. In the "worse" case the program can print one of two things, both, nothing, crash or fail to even compile. In the "better" case it can print one of 2 things. Neither set is good for you or I. There is no prediction of program behavior from the specification alone.

Comment: Guys i dont want to be rude, but may be you could move your conversation to some chat :-)

Comment: @davmac - Potential UB is a source of optimization. I'll finish this back and forth with a link to a talk by [Chandler Carruth](https://youtu.be/yG1OZ69H_-o?t=39m15s), and an apology to Filip.

Comment: @StoryTeller right (essentially because the compiler can assume it can't/won't/didn't happen), and that's another important difference between undefined and unspecified behaviour.